# How do I link a button in html with my python code? (django)

Tags: python, html, django

I'm working with django and I want to calculate something depending on what the user put on the selectboxes of my page, but I don't know how to connect that with my python code that calculates everything, please help :(

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please share what code you have and what you have already tried so we can help you figure out where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a html form element like this with method post and action="path_of_your_python_file"

```
<form name="search" action="calculate.py" method="GET">
      Search: <input type="checkbox" name="user_input">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then in calculate.py

```
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
searchterm =  form.getvalue('user_input')
// Do your calculation here
```

I think that will help